# Weka, Can't get nearest neighbor to work with current test and train set

Tags: machine-learning, weka

Currently I'm using Weka and I'm trying to use the nearest neighbor method to classify my test set. Both my train set and test set have 11 columns with numerical values, the last column being the one to classify. Both have been converted from .csv to .arff with the Weka tool.

[preview training set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1u1p5.png)

[preview test set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQngM.png)

First I uploaded the training set and in the "classify" tab under "test options" I checked "use training set". I selected the "IBk" classifier and put # of neighbors to 10. The (bad) output was this:

[image: training set classify]

Next I checked "supplied test set" and uploaded my test set. Only the last column is empty (apart from the header). But when I try to run it,I get the following output saying none were classified:

[image: testing set classify]

At this point I just don't understand what to do. As far as I can tell my test and train set are correct, as they are identical apart from the numerical values in the columns and I'm simply trying to use my test set after having trained on the train set... Somewhere I'm doing something terribly wrong.

Comment: So your classes are not nominal rather they are numeric? And what happens if you put ? in the class attribute's cells of the test file?

Comment: Hey Rushdi, well in essence they are nominal, but were replaced with numbers (ex. tree type 1 = 1). I changed it to nominal and now I get good results on using the training set, so thanks. But the test file remains the same issue: everything is put in unknown. Empty cells or "?" makes no difference.

I did notice however that in the testfile the class attribute was labelled as numeric. I changed the arff file to make it identical to the training set:

@attribute Cover_Type {aspen,lodgepole,spruce,krummholz,ponderosa,douglas,willow}

Comment: Cant edit the above anymore, but even after having applied the above class attribute line in the arff, all my instances from the test set still place as "unknown".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies with the evaluation on test set with class attributes set to `?` or `empty`. You will get some results on training sets because for training data, you know all the data labels. But for test set where your labels are unknown, how do you know that the classifier prediction `y` is a correct class for a given instance or simply a misclassification? That is why: **you can get the predicted labels of test instances but you cannot have any evaluation**.

**What follows is merely hypothetical and don't have any relation to your data:**

For instance, on training data, you might have something as follows:

```
=== Error on training data ===

Correctly Classified Instances           4               80      %
Incorrectly Classified Instances         1               20      %
Kappa statistic                          0.6154
Mean absolute error                      0.2429
Root mean squared error                  0.4016
Relative absolute error                 50.0043 %
Root relative squared error             81.8358 %
Total Number of Instances                5
```

But for unknown test data, the output might look something as follows:

```
=== Error on test data ===

Total Number of Instances                0     
Ignored Class Unknown Instances                  5     


=== Confusion Matrix ===

 a b   <-- classified as
 0 0 | a = 1
 0 0 | b = -1
```

However, you can have the predictions for the unknown data instances as follows:

```
=== Predictions on test data ===

 inst#     actual  predicted error prediction (feature1,feature2,feature3,feature4)
     1        1:?        1:1       1 (1,7,1,0)
     2        1:?        1:1       1 (1,5,1,0)
     3        1:?       2:-1       0.786 (-1,1,1,0)
     4        1:?       2:-1       0.861 (1,1,1,1)
     5        1:?       2:-1       0.861 (-1,1,1,1)

        === Confusion Matrix ===

         a b   <-- classified as
         2 1 | a = 1
     0 2 | b = -1
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for answering. Please correct me if I'm wrong, but basically I asked Weka to evaluate the classifier from the train set on the test set, but because the test set lacks a filled in class attribute, it puts everything in unknown?

Comment: So this time I did pretty much the same as before, but also clicked "more options" and selected prediction. It actually gives me a prediction for every instance now, thank you :). However, it lacks a confusion matrix for the predictions. Also, is there a way for me to retrieve the classification method that Weka has gained from the training set? Sorry if this is a bad question, I'm having a hard time understanding this :(.

Comment: For the first question: As your test set has all ? class labels, it does not know how to evaluate the predictions with actual labels. For the second question: Confusion matrix only can be found if you know your positive/negative labels and thus you can calculate the TP, FP, FN and TN. But as test data has no labels, there is no confusion matrix. The classification method depends on the choice of algorithm. e.g., for decision trees, you can right click on the model and view the tree to see the decision branches. But this varies. I would really appreciate if you could mark my answer as accepted.